# Moving Leap Motion Hands Coordinate System Following Spawned iPhone Player Camera

Tags: unity-game-engine, leap-motion

I'm fixing a legacy project two years ago. It uses a Windows Unity host to utilize Leap Motion device capturing hand movements, and an iPhone Player (with Cardboard headset) to control how the view ports move relatively in the "game world".

Now I find that only when my Leap Motion device keeps still (e.x. be pinned on my chest) and only the iPhone player moves with my head can I find everything okay. Otherwise, when I wear both the Leap Motion device and the iPhone on my head, the hand model sways with my head's moving.

I've concluded that the captured position of hands by Leap Motion device has been interpreted as position relative to the "world coordination system", but in fact it should be a local one relative to my headset (i.e. the iPhone player camera which is spawned as a game object in my windows host).

I've made a simplified scene to illustrate my situation. The hierarchy when network is not connected is like below:

[image: Windows End With Nothing Connected]

The hierarchy when the Windows program is connected to itself as the host:

[image: Windows Host With Itself Connected]

When iPhone End is also connected:

[image: Windows Host With Both iPhone And Itself Connected]

I'm trying to give command to "Hands" so that it rotates with "Camera(Clone)/Head", but it doesn't work. (In the following picture, "RotateWith" and "CameraFacing" are different trials to let it move with "Camera(Clone)/Head".)

[image: Inspector View Of "Hands"]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the problem is caused by the camera and the Leap Motion having different latencies and operating at different frame-rates, which can be solved with [temporal warping](https://developer-archive.leapmotion.com/documentation/v2/unity/unity/Unity.Prefab.LMHeadMountedRig.html#leap-vr-temporal-warping). This has already been implemented by Leap Motion and is done automatically if you use the [Leap XR Service Provider](https://leapmotion.github.io/UnityModules/core.html#xr-rig-setup).

Attach the `LeapXRServiceProvider` component to your Main Camera and ensure the Temporal Warping Mode is set to "Auto". This will tell the Leap Motion code to compensate for the differences between the hand tracking frame and the Unity frame.